# Can I say, "Building tunnels" or "new ring roads" can also do?

Tags: word-choice, do

> Building tunnels or new ring roads can also *do*.

Is using "do" in this way ungrammatical? "Do", in this sentence, would mean "work":

> Building tunnels or new ring roads can also *work*.

Comment: Can also do what?

Comment: In informal speech we can say "That will do", meaning "That will serve the purpose" or "That's enough" - but it isn't really appropriate if you're writing something serious about road building.

Comment: OK thanks......

Comment: Absent context, the question "Is using "do" in this way ungrammatical?" can be answered with "Perhaps", as we cannot be sure how you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

There are contexts where saying that something "will do" or "won't do" (with the emphasis placed on the word "do"), as a synonym for "will work" or "will be satisfactory", is perfectly appropriate.

I wouldn't say (as a commenter does) that the term is informal, but it is regarded as idiomatic, along with phrases like "make do" (i.e. find a way of performing only within means that are already available) or "it'll have to do" (I.e. you/we will have to be satisfied with what is available or already offered).

"Make do", for example, has been in popular British usage in the past, such as in the post-war policy of "make do and mend", so most people are familiar to some degree with this usage of "do".

"Could do with" is another idiom (meaning that something is desirable, or as an oblique way of saying that something is imperative or necessary) which follows a similar pattern, as is "can't be doing with" (meaning that a person, thing, or eventuality cannot be tolerated).

I would definitely say that the word "do" is not a straightforward substitute for the word "work". You wouldn't say "a ring road can also do" or "could also do".

The idiomatic way of saying this would be "a ring road *might* do", and if you had to add the word "also", then it wouldn't go between the words "might" and "do" (as in "might also do"), it would go before or after ("also might do", "might do also").

Comment: Can you imagine 'Alternatively, a ring road might do' in an official document? Even 'might work' here sounds off-register. 'A possible alternative would be the construction of a ring road' sounds like something a Committee of Works and Urban Planning would come up with.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I agree - your imagined example wouldn't do! But I think the problem might be the overall structure of the sentence in such cases, rather than the usage of "do". If you're trying to be pithy, and express all the same uncertainty and contingency, you could just say "other ideas include tunnels and ring roads".